# how do I create an alert for the ipad that looks like a black transparent box?

Tags: xcode, uiview, alert

similar to this image..

http://lh4.ggpht.com/__J8fmwUsWAg/TQqoQujrXLI/AAAAAAAAeeQ/SkOez_EiQWQ/2843141057.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom view with rounded corners, alpha around .4, background color black and a bit of text. Then add it to the current view when you want to display the alert.